# How can I use 'manual' as a trigger option for popovers in the Twitter Bootstrap framework?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

In the Twitter Bootstrap framework, both the Twipsy and Popover plugins list 'manual' as an option for triggering the tooltip. How would one use the manual option (i.e. what's the practical effect of that - how does the tooltip get activated)?

---

**Answer**
This is what I ended up using (making use of 'toggle'):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.popup-marker').popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'manual',
    }).click(function() {
        $(this).popover('toggle');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could activate it with:

```
$('#element').twipsy('show')
```

And then hide with:

```
$('#element').twipsy('hide')
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize the connection there. I also discovered that 'toggle' is available in addition to 'show' and 'hide', so I ended up using that. I'll edit my OP to show my solution.