# Twitter Bootstrap Popup ignores delay even with click-trigger

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

From the question/answer below, I understand that the hide option does not work when you call .popover("show") in JavaScript.

[Twitter Bootstrap Popup ignores delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842851/twitter-bootstrap-popup-ignores-delay)

But isn't it supposed to work when the popover is triggered by a mouse click?

In the jsFiddle below, you may click on the text and the popover is showed. But it does not hide after the delay.

```
$("#clickMe").popover({
    content: "Hello world",
    delay: { show : 100 , hide : 1000 }
});
```

.

```
   <span id="clickMe">Click me</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ahmed002/cwpB9/

Is it expected that the delay does not work in this case (and if yes, in which case does this option work)?

Answer (score 0):

Be patient :) The delay time is in milliseconds and also work for your fiddle.
Use longer times, click once and wait (10 seconds) and click again and wait 10 seconds again:

```
$("#clickMe").popover({
            content: "Hello world",
            delay: { show : 10000 , hide : 10000}
      });
```

Delay settings won't work if you set the trigger  to manual (see: [How can I use 'manual' as a trigger option for popovers in the Twitter Bootstrap framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898421/how-can-i-use-manual-as-a-trigger-option-for-popovers-in-the-twitter-bootstrap))

Comment: OMG!! You just helped me to realize that the user has to click a second time to hide the popover. That's very lame from Bootstrap to my opinion. Thank you Bass.

Answer (score 0):

The hide option of Bootstrap is not an auto-hide delay -> unfortunately, the user has to click to hide the popover. After that click the hide option of bootstrap will delay the hiding.

If you want the popover to auto-hide, use the following code. It defines a new jQuery function that places a bootstrap popover with auto-hide.

```
/****** Defines new jQuery functions */
jQuery.fn.extend({
    popoverWithAutoHide: function (popoverText) {
        $(this).popover({
            content : popoverText
        }).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
            var $this = $(this); // CLosure
            setTimeout(function() {
                 $this.popover("hide");
            }, 3000);
        });
    }
});
```

Basically, it activates an additionnal function as soon as the popover is shown. That function calls jQuery setTimeout to call a third function 3000ms later. That 3rd function closes the popover.

The usage is very simple:

```
$("#editButton").popoverWithAutoHide("To edit items, you need to be logged in and have a rank 5 or higher.");
```